# How do I upload an image for use in a question?

Tags: support, images

How do I upload an image for use in a question?

I can see the "Images" menu item, but the help assumes I have a link to the image. The image is something I created on my computer. Can I upload it to math.stackexchange.com and then use a link?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After clicking the button that looks like an image: [image: this one] you should see this grey "click here" field. It's one huge button; click it.

If you don't see it, check whether JavaScript is enabled in your browser.

[image]

Comment: Ah, yes! I was clicking the text "Images" rather than the image icon. Got it now. Thanks.